# Regex Java replacing ["item1", "item2"] with item1, item2

Tags: java, regex

I don't use regex that much so I am having some troubles with this right now.
I'm trying to replace `["item1", "item2"]` with `item1, item2` using `string.replaceAll()`.
However, I don't know how do I match the `[`, and I don't know how to replace all special characters but the comma.

Comment: You have to double escape the special metacharacters to match a literal instance.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for a JSON parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following regular expression to solve your problem.

```
String s = "[\"item1\", \"item2\"]";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[\"([a-z0-9]*)\",\\s*\"([a-z0-9]+)\"\\]", "$1, $2"));
```

Note that I have use parenthesis to group what I wanted and use them in the replace string. Your groups will identify as $1, $2, $3... as it appears in your regular expression.